# RegEx matches all text that applies to only some of the query?

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match-all

I'm working on a html parser for a client, and I have just started messing around with RegEx. I'm quite new to it but am learning quickly! In this part, I need to acquire all of the text that is 18.0pt size within the document. Here is the first RegEx I have tried (using a real-time RegEx tester):

```
<p.*?><span.*?style='.*?font-size:1
```

Here is my test text:

```
<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:14.0pt;font-family:"Comic Sans MS"'>3<sup>rd</sup>
Sunday in Lent - 2013c<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:14.0pt;font-family:"Comic Sans MS"'>Old
Testament – Isaiah 55:1-9<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:14.0pt;font-family:"Comic Sans MS"'>New
Testament – Luke 13:1-9<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Comic Sans MS"'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
</span></p>
```

It works correctly and highlights each line separately until the 1. **The problem is, right when I change 1 to 18, instead of highlighting just the line with font-size:18, it highlights ALL THE WAY from the first line until the 18.** I would like to just grab the line with 18pt font. Thank you, and any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: I think I understand why, because I put a nongreedy dot infront of it so it matches until it finds the 18, but I kind of need that there aswell, because in some cases there is extra styling, but some cases not. How can I get around this?

Comment: While it may be fun to learn parsing with regex, there are better ways to get what you want. Take a look at this earlier answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-and-mature-html-parser-for-php to get some ideas. Once the html is parsed, finding what you want is easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a better regexp:

```
<p[^>]*>[ \t\r\n]*<span[^>]* style='[^']*font-size:18
```

Your one is doing exactly as you told it; finding `<p`, then any number of arbitrary characters, then `><span`, then more arbitrary characters, then `font-size:18`. So it finds the first `<p` then all the *arbitrary characters* until `font-size:18`. You were just lucky in the first example that all your spans had font-size specified.

This version doesn't allow so much; stopping at any `>`. Also to make it more robust, I allowed whitespace between the `<p>` and `<span>`.

Comment: Just one question, where you have the [ \t\r\n]*, there is a possibility that there is another tag in there (such as <b>). How can I let it match anything in between those <p> and <span> tags?

Comment: do you need to match the <p> at all? It's quite complicated to match arbitrary tags, because regular expressions have no concept of recursion or DOM structure. If you need it to be that complex, you should use a library which is DOM-aware.

Comment: You're right.. I realized that after I finished rewriting it. This is what I came up with:    /<span.*?style='.*?font-size:18\.0pt.*?'>(.*?)(?:<o:p>)?(?:<\/o:p>)?<\/span>/si

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
regular expressions."  Now they have two problems." https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!msg/alt.religion.emacs/DR057Srw5-c/Co-2L2BKn7UJ

Comment: The regexp you posted has the same problem as your original; anywhere you use `.*` (incidentally `.*?` is not needed, because `*` means *0 or more* matches), you will match vast swathes of the text that you didn't expect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matching "any character" (with the dot), if you match "any character except newline" you will make sure not to go beyond the end of a line:

```
<p.*?><span[^\n]*?style='[^\n]*?font-size:18
```

Now usually the `.` doesn't match newline unless certain flags are set (which depends on your environment) - in particular, the `s` flag. Could it be that's the default for your regex tester?

Another thought would be to limit the number of characters you expect to match with {} - for example

```
<p.{,20}>
```

which will work as long as there's not more than 20 characters in your opening `<p>` tag.

Comment: Hey Floris. Thanks for the response! The thing is, this html page is being exported from a Word Document file, and I've realized that sometimes it adds random \n characters unfortunately.. so I've purposely enabled the /s modifier. Also, sometimes there are paragraphs of text so I can't really estimate the amount of characters.